# invariant violation: text string must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: react-native

I am simply trying to refactor some code and make a reusable button. I am getting this error and have no clue what the problem is, when I compare it to other reusable components it looks the exact same.

The reusable component:

```
const CustomButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.buttonStyle}
      onPress={props.onPress}
    >
      <Text>{props.text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

And then I am calling it in the render method like this:

```
<View>
      <Text>Due Date:</Text>
       <CustomButton
          text={'Next Class'}
       />
</View>
```

Comment: your code is correct, some other where you render text out of `<Text>` component probably!

Comment: hmmmmmm, ok check my edit

Comment: from what i just edited, it works if I remove this code so it's something in here

Comment: Still ok, see [here](https://snack.expo.io/@moh3n95/goolius_boozler)

Comment: Ok, so I literally just rewrote it the exact same and deleted the old code and now it works. No clue why that would happen but it's working. Thank you for the help.

Comment: cache...... ^^'

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I'm new to programming in general.